# Parsing date in string

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have strings that look like this:

```
Available. Released 2013, November
```

And I am looking for a way to fetch: Year, Month

I have this regex so far:

```
/Released \b\d{4}\b,\s?/.match('Released 2013, ')
```

But I am failing to see how would I grab the month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-scan) and capturing group:

```
text = <<EOS
Available. Released 2013, November
Available. Released 2012, October
EOS

text.scan(/Released\s+(\d{4},\s*[A-Z][a-z]+)/)
# => [["2013, November"], ["2012, October"]]

text.scan(/Released\s+(\d{4}),\s*([A-Z][a-z]+)/)
# => [["2013", "November"], ["2012", "October"]]
```

**UPDATE**

If you want only the first match, use [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
text[/Released\s+\d{4},\s*[A-Z][a-z]+/]
# => "Released 2013, November"
text[/Released\s+(\d{4},\s*[A-Z][a-z]+)/, 1]
# => "2013, November"
```

Comment: Ok, interesting. That means that in order to get the result I would need to do ``text.scan(/Released\s+(\d{4},\s*[A-Z][a-z]+)/).first.first``, right? I am sure that for each string will it just be one release date...

Comment: @HommerSmith, Do you want `2013, November` as a result? Then use `String#[]`: `text[/Released\s+\d{4},\s*[A-Z][a-z]+/]`.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know you could do that! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
s = <<_
Available. Released 2013, November
Available. Released 2012, October
_

s.each_line.map{|s| s.split("Released").last.strip}
# => ["2013, November", "2012, October"]

"Available. Released 2013, November".split("Released ").last
# => "2013, November"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any way I could improve this so I get a string with the release date instead of an array? I am sure that for each input there will be just one release date.

Comment: Given ``Available. Released 2013, November``, I would expect ``2013, November``

Answer (score 1):

I'd do using [`CSV::parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-parse) :

```
require 'csv'

text = <<EOS
Available. Released 2013, November
Available. Released 2012, October
EOS

ary = CSV.parse(text,:col_sep => " ").map do |a|
  a.last(2).join(" ")
end

ary # => ["2013, November", "2012, October"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the year and month are always the last two words of the line, as in

```
s = 'Available. Released 2013, November'
```

then

```
s.split.last(2).join(' ') #=> "2013, November"
```

would be enough.

Comment: What about your last solution, that made me crazy ?

Comment: You mean `[-2,2]` instead of `last(2)`?  6 one way, 0.5 dozen the other.